# Extract JavaDoc with Python

Tags: java, python, parsing, javadoc, trac

I'd like to integrate the documentation of a Java/Android project in a Trac instance. As Trac is written in Python I need a way to extract the JavaDoc comments from within Python.

Can anyone give me some hints how to accomplish this? I've thought of these two possibilities but I don't know if there are any libraries that can do this:

- Parse the whole Java source.
- Let JavaDoc do the job and somehow extract the docs from its output

Comment: For what purpose do you need what parts of the documentation? It might be easier to just use the generated JavaDoc as static files on your hosting server.

Comment: I'd just like some tighter integration into Trac like for example browsing the docs or easily referencing it from the wiki/tickets etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following solution: I've found something called [json-doclet](https://bitbucket.org/ananelson/json-doclet) which is kind of a Plugin for Javadoc that outputs a JSON which should be reasonably easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl), which is written in C++, can parse Javadoc and [output it as XML](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#xmlgenerator). You could call it from Python and then transform the XML into whatever format you like. (This will be more efficient if you do it in C++ using the `doxmlparser`, but you can also do it in Python.)

Comment: This would probably work but sadly Javadoc and Doxygen don't share exactly the same syntax.